# Enable blank for edit box

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I have a edit box on my tab, when I make it blank and try to click on other tab I'm getting an error in the form of popup as Enter a number? Please help , how to skip this error?

Comment: Please provide some sample code and the error you are getting.

Comment: What should happen if you blank the edit box and then you click on the OK button instead of clicking on another tab?

Answer (score 2):

You choose a `DDX_Text` save to contents of the edit control into a integer, long DWORD or anything else.

All `DDX_Text` that use a numeric value routines require an input, at least 0.

Either preset the input, so that the user can skip this, or use a different way to extract the data from the edit control. For example you can use `GetDlgItemInt` to get the value out of the edit control.